# How do I get to a field of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-objects

I'm trying to work out how to get to the anonymous return value from my WebApi Controller, it does something like this:

```
public IActionResult Get() {
    using var db = DbDataContextFactory.Make();
    return Ok(new {
        feedTypes = db.GetStatisticsAllFeeds()
    });
}
...
IDictionary<string, ExpandoObject> GetStatisticsAllFeeds(this DbDataContext db) {}
```

Out of interest I want to call the Controllers Get and look at the returned data, easy right?

If I do this this:

```
... instantiate controller ...
IActionResult actionResult = sut.Get();
var okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
dynamic anon = okObjectResult.Value;
```

I can see that the anon object has a field called 'feedTypes' in the debugger

If I do This:

```
Type type = anon.GetType();
var fields = type.GetProperties();
foreach (var field in fields) {
    string name = field.Name;
    var temp = field.GetValue(anon, null);
    Console.WriteLine(name + "  " + temp);
}
```

I can see the the anon object has a feedTypes field.

But if I do this

```
var ft = anon.feedTypes;
```

I get the exception

An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code: ''**object' does not contain a definition for 'feedTypes''**

How can I get to the actual field e.g.

IDictionary dict = anon.FeedTypes ... what goes here?

TIA.

Comment: @RufusL it seems, that OP is using it already `Type type = anon.GetType()` and so on

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you're right, I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: You've already demonstrated that you know how to get a property value from a dynamic type. What specifically is the question here?

Comment: you can't cast anonymous type to dynamic, but what you can do is anon.GetType().GetProperty("feedTypes").GetValue(anon)

Comment: you can also try JObject.FromObject(anon)["feedTypes"]

Comment: or just create normal class for it since you probably misused anonymous type